# Getting dependency error for sparksession and SQLContext

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, dependencies

I am getting dependency error for my SQLContext and sparksession in my spark program

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
```

Error for SQLCOntext

```
Symbol 'type org.apache.spark.Logging' is missing from the classpath. This symbol is required by 'class org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext'. Make sure that type Logging is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with -Ylog-classpath. A full rebuild may help if 'SQLContext.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of org.apache.spark.
```

Error for SparkSession:

```
not found: value SparkSession
```

Below are the spark dependencies in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0-cdh5.15.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-cloudera1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-catalyst_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0-cdh5.15.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-test-tags_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0-cdh5.15.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have both Spark 2 and Spark 1.6 dependencies defined in your project.
`org.apache.spark.Logging` is not available in Spark 2 anymore.

Change

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-cloudera1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0-cdh5.15.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This solved the SQLContext error but still getting error for SparkSession

Comment: Well, did you import it ? `import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession`

Comment: I imported it but its not present, however I updated my pom with different version of spark and i am not getting error for spark session